# How to use jQuery $.ajax to open a pdf w/out a post-back?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

I have a very dynamic UI that provides the end user 2 detail views (each one a step deeper than the previous).  When i get to the bottom of this chain I would like the ability to "preview" a pdf file ... but the only luck I have thus far is using window.open(url) and this pops up an additional browser window in IE6/7 (not desired if at all possible)

My question is this - how "should" I structure this type of functionality if I can generate a pdf on the server side (no problem) and want to display this to the user w/out a post-back?

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is just a wrapper for javascript - it can only weave so much magic - you still have finite options here.  Window.Open or an Iframe.  Or perhaps you can find some sort of activex component to background load a pdf? - or perhaps it's possible to interpret and render a pdf in javascript.. but I doubt that would be a pleasent UI experience.

tough one, hope this helps.

Comment: does adobe have a activeX component?  if so you could render it out beforehand, if someone requests a pdf, pull the bytes in and link it to the component?  totally guess here, never even had a problem close to this.

Comment: that might be possible, but I'm trying to keep this cross browser and would like to avoid active-x unless it's the only option ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preview a PDF inline, the only way to do that is to render an image on the server, and load that.